# Scala - Sort by Optional fields, with None value last

Tags: scala, sorting, optional-values

I have the following class :

```
final case class PowerDetails (
  [...],
  label: String,
  title: String,
  category: String,
  idCategory: Option[String],
  numCategory: Option[Int]
)
```

I need to sort a list of `PowerDetails` like this :

> Elements having a value for  `idCategory`  and  `numCategory`  should be before the `None` , and ordered by  `idCategory`  and then  `numCategory`.   As for the `None` values, they need to be ordered by the fields  `category` , `title` , `label`.

If possible, I would like to avoid extending `Ordered`

```
final case class PowerDetails (

   ...

) extends Ordered[PowerDetails] {

    override def compare(that: PowerDetails): Int = {
       // Define here the comparison
    }

}
```

I tried creating an Ordering as below and then use the `sorted` function, but I'm getting a `NullPointerException`

```
  implicit val orderingPowers = optionOrdering.thenComparing(ordering)

  val ordering: Ordering[PowerDetails] = Ordering[(String, String, String)]
    .on[PowerDetails](powerDetail =>
      ( powerDetail.category, powerDetail.title, powerDetail.label))

  val optionOrdering : Ordering[PowerDetails] = Ordering[(Option[String], Option[Int])]
    .on[PowerDetails](powerDetail =>
      (powerDetail.idCategory, powerDetail.numCategory))
```

Could you please help me find out how to do it ?
Thanks.

Comment: Have you tried putting `ordering` ahead of `optionOrdering`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's another approach also using [`Ordering.by`](https://www.scala-lang.org/api/2.13.0/scala/math/Ordering$.html#by[T,S](f:T=%3ES)(implicitord:scala.math.Ordering[S]):scala.math.Ordering[T]) along with Option's `isEmpty`, leveraging `false < true` for the wanted `Some/None` ordering:

```
final case class PowerDetails (
  field1: String,
  field2: Int,
  label: String,
  title: String,
  category: String,
  idCategory: Option[String],
  numCategory: Option[Int]
)

implicit val PDOrderer: Ordering[PowerDetails] = Ordering.by{
  case PowerDetails(_, _, label, title, cat, idCat, numCat) =>
    (idCat.isEmpty, idCat, numCat.isEmpty, numCat, cat, title, label)
}
```

Comment: Just tried this one. It works like a charm, thanks !!

Comment: What is the order of `Some(2).isEmpty` and `Some(6).isEmpty`?

Comment: `Some(2).isEmpty == Some(6).isEmpty`, but `(Some(2).isEmpty, Some(2)) < (Some(6).isEmpty, Some(6))` with the implicit orderer.

Answer (score 2):

Would this work for you?

```
implicit val PDOrd :Ordering[PowerDetails] = Ordering.by(
  pd => (pd.idCategory.getOrElse("~~~~")
       , pd.numCategory.getOrElse(Int.MaxValue)
       , pd.category
       , pd.title
       , pd.label ))
```

Admittedly `"~~~~"` isn't the end of the `String` universe, but it should work in most cases.

Comment: thanks, but I'd rather not use  `getOrElse`. I'll keep it in mind though, if I can't find anything else